# How to remove the shadow effect of textbox in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on an existing project and the textbox has these shadowed edges. Can someone please help me how to remove this effect?

http://postimg.org/image/5ry6evj5p/

Thank you!

Comment: It is written in ReactJS and you might find it differnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify you css with the setting you prefer .. 
for twitter-bootstrap 3 the tag element and class involved should be (the value setted are for sample)

```
.form-control, input {
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

or you can redifine the class and the elemnt stule in you page on with a inline styling

Comment: Thank you very much man! http://postimg.org/image/4u3td4mvz/ I still see it a little bit though!

Comment: Yes is much better .. .you can also set style directly in the input element and see what's happen